# Migrate Issue on Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, heroku-postgres, heroku-cli

I have hosted the `django` application in `Heroku` environmnet. Whenever I try to initiate **migrate** command its shows **error:**

> Your models have changes that are not yet reflected in a migration,
> and so won't be applied. Run 'manage.py makemigrations' to make new
> migrations, and then re-run 'manage.py migrate' to apply them. Run
> 'manage.py makemigrations' to make new migrations, and then re-run
> 'manage.py migrate' to apply them.

I also checked with **new** database on same application eventhough same issue. Finally I have tried **makemigrations** its done well, but after **makemigrations** also having same issue. The same I have tried with another `application` in same `heroku` **makemigrations** and **migrate** working well.

Please suggest why I can't migrate on previous application in `heroku`.

[image]

Comment: Go to `heroku>your app>more>run console>heroku run bash`..Here run **makemigrations** and **migrate** command..

Comment: Hi have tried eventhough same issue.

Comment: did you find a solution ? im having the same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here two way to solve this problem:

1. Don't run `makemigrations` command in Heroku bash.
   Run makemigrations locally to create migration files and Run migrate **locally** then **commit** the result and **push**, and then run **migrate** command on `Heroku`.

**OR**

2. If your **existing** database have not contain any **useful** data then **destroy** it :-

> Go to heroku **>>** your app **>>** Resources **>>** select Heroku
> Postgres **>>** Settings **>>** select Destroy Database..

After this follow again first way.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue so in resolving it I removed `/migrations` dir in .gitignore for the main/master branch (or your own deployment branch). While every other developer's branch has /migrations dir in their .gitignore - so their personal migrations don't get tracked in git.

That way, there'll be minimal chance of having a merge conflict in migrations files, since no developer's migration is tracked in git.

Finally, remember to;

1. git switch to main/master (or your deployment branch) locally (git switch main)
2. pull the latest merged code from origin (git pull)
3. run your manage.py makemigrations (python ./manage.py makemigrations)
4. now there should be new/updated migrations locally, add them to your git (git add . ) then git commit your new changes and push to origin (git push)
5. Manually push to heroku; (git push heroku main:main)...edit accordingly if your deployment branch isn't set to main.
6. Go into your dyno console (heroku run bash --app ) and apply the migrations (python manage.py migrate)